# How to use jQuery nth-child to color every other div in parent and rest on new parent?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, jquery-traversing

Have to support IE8 so no just css.

I am trying to color the odds and evens of each parent div and reset the color when it hits the new parent div.  Hope that makes sense.  Here is an example:

```
<div class="date">
<h2>Content</h2>
(White BGColor this div)<div class="option-heading"> 
    <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
    <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
(ignore)<div class="option-content">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
(Blue BGColor this div)<div class="option-heading"> 
    <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
    <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
(ignore)<div class="option-content">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
(White BGColor this div)<div class="option-heading"> 
    <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
    <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
(ignore)<div class="option-content">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
</div>
(reset to color first white)
<div class="date">
<h2>Content</h2>
(White BGColor this div)<div class="option-heading"> 
    <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
    <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
(ignore)<div class="option-content">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
(Blue BGColor this div)<div class="option-heading"> 
    <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
    <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
(ignore)<div class="option-content">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I use this jQuery

```
           $ ('div.option-heading p:odd').css("background-color","#e3e8ea");
       $ ('div.option-heading p:even').css("background-color","#fff");
```

But it doesn't reset on the new parent div.

Comment: Thanks all for you input.  Answer:


$('div.date').each(function() {
   $(this).find('div.option-heading p:odd').css('background-color', '#e3e8ea');
   $(this).find('div.option-heading p:even').css('background-color','#fff');
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a loop on the parent elements so every time the code reaches a new parent element (`<div class="date"></div>` in your case), it will reset the styles:

```
$('div.date').each(function() {
  $(this).find('div.option-heading:odd').css('background-color', '#e3e8ea');
  $(this).find('div.option-heading:even').css('background-color','#fff');
});
```

Comment: Used this and didn't work added the p:odd p:even = worked :]

$('div.date').each(function() {
      $(this).find('div.option-heading p:odd').css('background-color', '#e3e8ea');
  $(this).find('div.option-heading p:even').css('background-color','#fff');
});

Comment: I don't see where you have the `<p>` element except for where the `<p>Content</p>` is, but if it worked for you, great.

Comment: Right - oddly enough without the p: it does nothing.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment, this might do it.

```
<div class="date">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <div class="option-heading"> 
        <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
        <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option-content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option-heading"> 
        <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
        <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option-content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option-heading"> 
        <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
        <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option-content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="date">
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <div class="option-heading"> 
        <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
        <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option-content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option-heading"> 
        <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
        <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="option-content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>


$('.date').each(function () {
    var $date = $(this);
    $('div.option-heading:odd', $date).css("background-color","#e3e8ea");
    $('div.option-heading:even', $date).css("background-color","#fff");
});
```

Comment: No dice... still doesn't reset to color the first item white on the new date div. It colors every other white blue white blue (which it did before).  What I need it to do is white blue white (new date div come reset count) white blue (new date div) white.

Answer (score 0):

Even and odd are base on the children position. Since the `p` is in most case the only children of the `div`, they are almost all first-child or in your case `odd`.

Use their index instead:

```
$('.date').each(function(){
    $(this).find('div.option-heading p').css("background-color", function(i){
        return i%2 ? '#e2e8ea' : '#fff';
    });
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mc3VT/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can set a personal attrubute to the divs, if you did it you would use the nex code

```
<p myAttr='odd'>···</p>
<p myAttr='even'>···</p>
```

and in jquery code

```
$ ('div.option-heading p[myAttr=odd]').css("background-color","#e3e8ea");
$ ('div.option-heading p[myAttr=even]').css("background-color","#fff");
```

and remember that DOM objects wont be affected  by the code, for that you need to execute these lines after create the DOM objects, or using pure css

```
p[myAttr=odd]{background-color:#e3e8ea;}
p[myAttr=even]{background-color:#fff;}
```